# Problems with Time Capsule full restore from Leopard to Mountain Lion

Tags: time-machine

I have a backup of my OS X Leopard on Time Capsule. In the meantime I've upgraded to Mountain Lion. When I try to restore from Time Capsule in full it takes me back to Leopard.

In Mountain Lion they want you to use the OS x restore which I did and got me back to leopard or if I use Mountain Lion time capsule feature they want you to find each file and restore it separately, which would take forever.

How would I go about restoring all my information and files from my old backup to have on Mountain Lion?

Should I take another backup with my time capsule, so it has an updated OS X or shoule I just do them separately?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Normally you should achieve what you want by using the Migration Assistant and searching your backup volume. Then you'll need to import everything except system files. Is that what you already did?!